# File encrypt by format

Tags: format, jpeg, decode, encode, docx

I am new to computers, and I want to know if there is a way to make files two-format-usable. For example, there is a jpg format file, but actually it is a docx format file, and we can decode it by changing the file format from .jpg to .docx. Can anyone help me? Thanks!!!

Comment: @zaph I want to make an encrypted file, which i can view it by changing the file format.  For example, the original file type is jpg, which looks like a picture, so people will just ignore the picture, but it is actually a confidentail docx document, I want to make it viewable by changing the file format from jpg to docx.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the file extension does not change the file data or format. It does keep some programs from opening the file.

This is done often on .zip files, changing the file extension to something different. This just adds confusion, not security.

If you want security encrypt the file data with a key and use any extension you choose. The password can  be something you enter on encryption and again of later opening that will decrypt the file.

Comment: Thanks for telling me these, I will try later.